# How to prevent XSS attacks with SpringMVC + Jackson Application?

Tags: spring-mvc, xss, security, jackson

The [Cross Site Scripting Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) has many rules for securing against XSS attacks. I would like to implement those suggestions in my web app which is using Spring MVC + Jackson + JPA  + Hibernate Bean Validation. As an example consider the following code that is similar to what I have in my app.

```
public class MessageJson {
    @NotEmpty // Bean Validation annotation  
    private String title; 

    @NotEmpty
    private String body; 

    // ... etc getters / setters
}

public class BolgPostController 
{ 
     
     @RequestMapping(value="messages",method=RequestMethod.POST) 
     public void createMessage(@Valid @RequestBody MessageJson message)
     {
           // **Question** How do I check that the message title and body don't contain 
           // nasty javascripts and other junk that should not be there? 

           // Call services to write data to the datababse
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="messages",method=RequestMethod.get) 
     public @ResponseBody List<MessageJson> createMessage()
     {
           // get data from the database 

           // **Question** How do I escape all the data in the list of MessageJson before 
            I send it back to the data. 
     }
}
```

I can see the following ways to implement the cheat sheet rules:

- **Option A** Implement them manually in each controller method.
- **Option B** Configure some extension to Spring MVC that can do it for me automatically
- **Option C** Configure Jackson so that it can do it for me since most of my input/output goes through Jackson

I am looking for some example configurations of SpringMVC in any of those three options, with a preference for option B and C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be easiest to do in setters for properties (like `setTitle()` for `title` property), when reading JSON.

Or if you are thinking of escaping additional characters (to, say, prevent embedding of HTML markup), have a look at this blog entry: [escaping HTML characters in JSON with Jackson](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/08/entry_476.html).

Comment: This is the simplest solution, I am using it with the http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com it works very well.